# Error: Linking requires a build-time setting `scheme` in the project's Expo config (app.config.js or app.json)

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-router, expo-dev-client

I created the project using [react-native expo bare-workflow](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/overview/)

```
npx create-expo-app --template bare-minimum
```

After creating the project, I tried to install **[expo-router](https://docs.expo.dev/router/installation/)** to the project, everything is done according to the `expo documentation`, even added `scheme` in `app.json` file. But, this `error` pops in `development build`, everything works fine in `expo go build`.

> WARN  Linking requires a build-time setting `scheme` in the project's
> Expo config (app.config.js or app.json) for production apps, if it's
> left blank, your app may crash. The scheme does not apply to
> development in the Expo client but you should add it as soon as you
> start working with Linking to avoid creating a broken build. Learn
> more: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/linking/

> ERROR  Error: Linking requires a build-time setting `scheme` in the
> project's Expo config (app.config.js or app.json) for bare or
> production apps. Manually providing a `scheme` property can circumvent
> this error. Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/linking/, js
> engine: hermes

***Thanks!***

Answer (score 0):

I have this same warning. Turn out I did not put `"scheme": "yourapp"` inside of `"expo": { ... }`. I placed it on the outside of it. Maybe you are doing the same thing.

It should look something like this.

```
{
    "expo": {
        ...snip...
        "scheme": "yourapp"
    }
...snip...
}
```